# Change Javascript Variables Using <input>

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

Title says it all. Is there any way of changing javascript variables using the html  tag?

Comment: You can read the value of an `input` in JavaScript, yes.  Have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var variable = document.getElementById("id").value
```

Your `<input>` should have an id, but there are different ways to get an element with javascript.

You should read a nice tutorial about javascript and HTML to get the basic knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't touched javascript in ages.